# Nosql or sql database for big temp data

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I'm new to the data world.

I want to store a temporary data in a database. The volume might be 10000 rows per transaction. Data will be removed in less than 1 hour (based on creationTime). There wont be any complex queries and there might be 1000 or more transaction per minute.

For this need, which database type would be useful?

Comment: Please provide more information about how is structured your data. Whether you need to "ACID" or BASE is enough or whether it must be distributed to multiple machines to avoid data loss.  You are on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the data structure and the use cases, not on the volume. If the data follows always the same structure, I‘d go for SQL. If the data sets are not easy to structure (e.g. have many different fields but only a few filled most of the time), NoSQL seems to be the better match.

There are databases for both types, which are able to handle large amounts of data.